# Erro criação foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraint

Estou criando duas referências de foreign key apontando para duas tabelas diferentes, porem estou recebendo erro na criação de uma delas.

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'dbo.TB_PODERES' that match the referencing column list in the foreign
>   key 'FK_TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES_TB_PODERES'.

A tabela de referência é a seguinte

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_PODERES](
    [ID_PDR] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CD_PODER] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [NM_PODER] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IC_ATIVO] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TB_PODERES_PODER] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_PDR] ASC,
    [CD_PODER] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

e a tabela que estou criando a FK é essa.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES](
    [ID_GPP] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_GRP_PDR] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CD_PODER] [char](10) NOT NULL, 
    [IC_ATIVO] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_GPP],[ID_GRP_PDR],[CD_PODER] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES_TB_PODERES FOREIGN KEY([CD_PODER])
    REFERENCES [dbo].TB_PODERES ([CD_PODER])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES_TB_PODERES
GO
```

Comment: Verifique se a chave primária da tabela TB_PODERES é realmente o par (ID_PDR, CD_PODER). Se for, qual coluna na tabela TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES se refere à coluna ID_PDR da tabela TB_PODERES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas usar na `FK` o mesmo numero de colunas que na `PK`.
Neste caso, tens uma `PK` composta por `[ID_PDR],[CD_PODER]` a tua `FK` também precisa de 2 columnas do mesmo tipo de dados.

Espero que te ajude.

Experimentei o teu script e adicionei esta coluna `ID_PDR` à tabela `[TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES]`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_PODERES](
    [ID_PDR] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CD_PODER] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [NM_PODER] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IC_ATIVO] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TB_PODERES_PODER] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_PDR] ASC,
    [CD_PODER] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES](
    [ID_GPP] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_GRP_PDR] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CD_PODER] [char](10) NOT NULL, 
    [IC_ATIVO] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ID_PDR] [int],
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_GPP],[ID_GRP_PDR],[CD_PODER] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES_TB_PODERES FOREIGN KEY([ID_PDR],[CD_PODER])
    REFERENCES [dbo].TB_PODERES ([ID_PDR],[CD_PODER])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_GRUPOS_PODERES_PODERES_TB_PODERES
GO
```